# How to Feed Batched Sequences of Images through Tensorflow conv2d

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, conv-neural-network

This seems like a trivial question, but I've been unable to find the answer.

I have batched sequences of images of shape:

`[batch_size, number_of_frames, frame_height, frame_width, number_of_channels]`

and I would like to pass each frame through a few convolutional and pooling layers. However, TensorFlow's `conv2d` layer accepts 4D inputs of shape:

`[batch_size, frame_height, frame_width, number_of_channels]`

My first attempt was to use `tf.map_fn` over axis=1, but I discovered that [this function does not propagate gradients](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3972).

My second attempt was to use `tf.unstack` over the first dimension and then use `tf.while_loop`. However, my `batch_size` and `number_of_frames` are dynamically determined (i.e. both are `None`), and `tf.unstack` raises `{ValueError} Cannot infer num from shape (?, ?, 30, 30, 3)` if `num` is unspecified. I tried specifying `num=tf.shape(self.observations)[1]`, but this raises `{TypeError} Expected int for argument 'num' not <tf.Tensor 'A2C/infer/strided_slice:0' shape=() dtype=int32>.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since all the images (`num_of_frames`) are passed to the same convolutional model, you can stack both batch and frames together and do the normal convolution. Can be achieved by just using `tf.resize` as shown below:

---

```
# input with size [batch_size, frame_height, frame_width, number_of_channels
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None, None,32,32,3])

# reshape for the conv input
x_reshapped = tf.reshape(x,[-1, 32, 32, 3])
```

x_reshapped output size will be `(50, 32, 32, 3)`

```
# define your conv network
y = tf.layers.conv2d(x_reshapped,5,kernel_size=(3,3),padding='SAME')
#(50, 32, 32, 3)

#Get back the input shape
out = tf.reshape(x,[-1, tf.shape(x)[1], 32, 32, 3])
```

The output size would be same as the input: `(10, 5, 32, 32, 3`

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
   sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

   print(sess.run(out, {x:np.random.normal(size=(10,5,32,32,3))}).shape)
   #(10, 5, 32, 32, 3)
```

Comment: Yeah, my roommate pointed this out. I guess it's the simplest solution :D